# יְשׁוּעָ֑ה ( Yeshua) in Isaiah 52: 7 refer directly to the Messiah?

Tags: word-study, isaiah, messiah

Does יְשׁוּעָ֑ה ( Yeshua) in Isaiah 52: 7 refer directly to the Messiah ? Is this a poetic play on words? ie, a proper noun to describe salvation, referring to the coming Saviour/ Messiah in cryptic poetry ?. I ask this because a famous Rabbi ( Tovia Singer), mocks Christians in Jerusalem by explaining how משיח does not appear in Isaiah 52 to 54. Therefore Isaiah 53 does not refer to an individual but to the nation Israel

> **Isaiah 52:7 [NIV]**: How beautiful on the mountains are the feet of those who bring good news, who proclaim peace, who bring good tidings, who proclaim salvation, who say to Zion, “Your God reigns!”

> **Isaiah 52:7[KJV]**: How beautiful upon the mountains are the feet of him that bringeth good tidings, that publisheth peace; that bringeth good tidings of good, that publisheth salvation; that saith unto Zion, Thy God reigneth!

> **Isaish 52:7 [Chabad]**: How beautiful are the feet of the herald on the mountains, announcing peace, heralding good tidings, announcing salvation, saying to Zion, "Your God has manifested His kingdom."

> זמַה־נָּאו֨וּ עַל־הֶֽהָרִ֜ים רַגְלֵ֣י מְבַשֵּׂ֗ר מַשְׁמִ֧יעַ שָׁל֛וֹם מְבַשֵּׂ֥ר ט֖וֹב מַשְׁמִ֣יעַ יְשׁוּעָ֑ה אֹמֵ֥ר לְצִיּ֖וֹן מָלַ֥ךְ אֱלֹהָֽיִךְ: **Isaish 52:7 [Chabad]**

Comment: It would assist your audience if you quoted the text to which you refer and cited your source, please. I don't know which text or which translation you are using.

Comment: The term there used refers to 'salvation' as an abstract noun of quality. Moreover, the context of Isaiah 53 doesn't allow us to conclude he refers to Israel as a nation, but to an individual one.

Answer (score 1):

It is instructive to show Isaiah 52:7 in its poetic parallel format:

```
How beautiful on the mountains are the feet of those 
   who bring good news,
   who proclaim peace,
   who bring good tidings,
   who proclaim **salvation**,
   who say to Zion, “Your God reigns!”
```

salvation,
יְשׁוּעָ֑ה (yə·šū·‘āh)
Noun - feminine singular
Strong's 3444: **Something saved**, deliverance, aid, victory, prosperity

The Hebrew word here is not a proper noun. It is a noun that served as the object of the verb proclaim. It does not directly refer to the Messiah.
It is the subject that may allude to Jesus the Messiah. He is the one who proclaims salvation.

שׁוּעָ֑ה ( Yeshua) in Isaiah 52: 7 refer directly to the Messiah?

No, not directly. Perhaps, indirectly if you want to use some poetic cryptic method of interpretation.